# How to hide a document that was clicked/viewed by the currently login user in firestore database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How to hide a document that was clicked/viewed by the current login user in firestore database? Whenever new data is render from firestore database it must not have a document that was clicked/viewed by this currently login user.

the `componentDidMount()` below is making the call to firestore

```
componentDidMount() {


    firebase.firestore().collection("Users").limit(2)
        .onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {

            var details = [];

            querySnapshot.forEach(function (doc) {
                details.push(doc.data());
            });

            console.log(details)
        });

}
```

and this is where the user would click to view the document/user that was fetched

```
<FlatList
        data={details}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View
              style={{backgroundColor: '#9a7caa', height: 150,width: 150, margin: 20,}}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.showUser}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text>{item.book}</Text>
                <Text>{item.number}</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Where do you maintain a list of all things clicked by a user?

Comment: This could be done by adding a child node in Firebase `is_hidden: true/false`, When the user clicks the row, set the flag to true. From then forward you would only load documents where is_hidden is false. Alternately, you could add a child node `users_who_have_seen_this:` and then any user that clicks on it, add a child node of their user id with a value of true. From there forward only load and show the nodes that do not have their user id within `users_who_have_seen_this:`

Comment: hi thanks @Jay the query would look something like this ```firebase.firestore().collection("Users").where("users_who_have_seen_this", "!=", "users_who_have_seen_this")``` but firestore do not have a ```"!="```(not equal)  query any suggests?

Comment: Sure. You would need to add a *is_hidden* field to all of your documents and set to true or false, then you could query for all *is_hidden isEqualToFalse*. Likewise you could add a *is_visible* to all documents and query for *is_visible isEqualToTrue*. The end result is the same. Likewise, for the *users_who_have_seen_this* node you could add the *uid: false*. You can also query for fields that have a null value so you could use that as a placeholder as well.